# How many alphabets and numbers special characters in textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

When i have enter the textfield text in that, How to count how many alphabets and numbers and special characters in textfield. Its display in 
three labels. How to count the alphabets and numbers.

I am a new iOS developer please help me on that.

Comment: use this method func textField(_ textField: UITextField,  shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,  replacementString string: String) -> Bool

Comment: Sorry I can't submit answer because your question is duplicate.